# User input doesn't print what i assigned it to print

Tags: python-3.x

So I have some code that asks a question and if the user input is y it goes on but when someone puts `n` or anything else it puts up a function and asks the question again without printing what I put for it.

I have already tried to change a whole bunch of things including rearranging things and taking out things but none of it worked Any help is very appreciated.

```
def Time():
    words = "Shall we play a game? Y or N: "
    for char in words:
        sleep(.14)
        sys.stdout.write(char)
        sys.stdout.flush()
    return(char)
if input(Time()) == 'y':
    Games()

elif input(Time()) == 'n':
    print("Too bad.")
    quit()

else:
    print("Thats not a option. Try again",(Time))
```

On:

```
if input(Time()) == 'y':
              Games()
```

That works if I enter anything else it doesn't work. it puts out the question again or a function output

Comment: What are you trying to do? Just run `Games` if the user enters y?

Comment: Yes basically, if the user picks y then it runs the function Games and if the user presses n then it quits the program,  if anything else is put in it prints Thats not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling `input` for each condition, you should call it once and keep the answer in a variable. Try doing this instead:

```
while True:
  answer = input("Shall we play a game? Y or N: ").lower()
  if answer == "y":
    Games()
  elif answer == "n":
    print("Too bad.")
    quit()
  else:
    print("Thats not a option. Try again")
```

This will also ask if you want to play again after the `Games` function finishes.